# How to add more options to sending files

Tags: ios, swift

I created code to send via email or print the file.

But I want to add more options such as sending via Gmail, saving the file to iBooks, saving to Dropbox, etc.

I have added two needs: email and print.
I want to add a Gmail and several options.

Here is the code:

```
func actionMenuViewControllerShareDocument(_ actionMenuViewController: ActionMenuViewController) {
    let mailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
    if let lastPathComponent = pdfDocument?.documentURL?.lastPathComponent,
        let attachmentData = pdfDocument?.dataRepresentation() {

        mailComposeViewController.addAttachmentData(attachmentData, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: lastPathComponent)
    }
}

func actionMenuViewControllerPrintDocument(_ actionMenuViewController: ActionMenuViewController) {
    let printInteractionController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
    printInteractionController.printingItem = pdfDocument?.dataRepresentation()
    printInteractionController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Code 2

```
import UIKit

class ActionMenuViewController: UITableViewController {
    weak var delegate: ActionMenuViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        tableView.separatorInset = .zero
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            delegate?.actionMenuViewControllerShareDocument(self)
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            delegate?.actionMenuViewControllerPrintDocument(self)

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}

protocol ActionMenuViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func actionMenuViewControllerShareDocument(_ actionMenuViewController: ActionMenuViewController)
    func actionMenuViewControllerPrintDocument(_ actionMenuViewController: ActionMenuViewController)

}
```

Comment: Instead of doing all of this yourself, use `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: @rmaddy In fact I do not want to use it

Comment: Just to be clear, instead of giving a user a standard, flexible set of options that allows them to decide how they want to use the file, you want to give them a non-standard, limited choice of options. On top of that, you want to write much more code than necessary just to make the user's app experience worse. Now that we have that clear, what is your question? We know you want to add Gmail but that's not a question.

Comment: @rmaddy I have an application that will modify the PDF files
If you add text and use `UIActivityViewController` and want to send it via email, the text you added does not appear. I do not know why

But in the way I added in my subject I can find the text after sending to the email or anywhere I have tried it

Comment: If your actual issue has to do with sending a modified PDF file using a `UIActivityViewController` them why not post a question about that issue?

Comment: @rmaddy can you just help me with my subject ?

Comment: Did you read what I asked you earlier? What is your question? We know you want to add Gmail but that's not a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, you will get several options  such as sending via Gmail, saving the file to iBooks, saving to Dropbox, etc which are support by iPhone.

Let's say, you have a .pdf file into your document directory.

```
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory: String = paths[0]
    let fullPath: String = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("\("FileName").pdf").absoluteString
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: fullPath)
    let activityItems = [url]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash

    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: @mostafizur-rahman-mafi i tried  your code but dosen't give me any action

Comment: Try again and let us know if you still facing any problem

Comment: I used the code but when I click Print, for example the PDF file does not appear

Comment: Store a pdf file into your iPhone document directory and try to read the file from the directory.

Comment: No new the same problem

Comment: You are facing problem because you don't create any pdf file into your iPhone document directory.

Comment: I added a PDF file and when I send via email or print the file nothing appears

Comment: and i added here `("\("FileName").pdf")` my pdf file name